# Custom SXA component does not appear in home page toolbox

Tags: sxa, sitecore-commerce, habitathome

I tried to develop a custom SXA component on top of Habitat Home Commerce demo (Sitecore 9.0.2). The custom SXA component is showing in all pages' toolbox, but not home page toolbox.

Is there any configuration I need to configure in order my custom SXA component to appear in Habitat Home page SXA toolbox?

[Update 1]: Even though I'm not able to perform the drag and drop due to missing of my custom SXA component in the toolbox, but I'm able to add my custom SXA component by clicking "Add Here" button.

[Update 2]: My custom SXA component finally appears in the toolbox after perform few build deployment to my local and resetting the IIS. I believe this may due to some Sitecore caching.

Comment: Can you check the placeholder you have available on the homepage and the corresponding placeholder settings? That would be my first guess if component restrictions are different between pages (and the SXA toolbox is smart enough to take that into account)

Comment: @Gatogordo There isn't any placeholder settings in my home page or any other page. I'm able to find and add the missing custom SXA component by clicking the "Add Here" button instead of the drag and drop.